# Error with ggscatterplot() function from ggpubr package

Tags: r, ggpubr

I try to use ggscatter() function from ggpubr package with the following code

```
ggscatter(mtcars, 
             x = "hp", y = "carb", 
             cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "spearman", 
             xlab = "x1", ylab = "x2")
```

but I get the following error.

> Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : :1:16: unexpected ','
> 1: italic(R)~`=`~0,

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your question as your code is working fine.

Sample data:

```
data(mtcars)
```

Sample code:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggscatter(mtcars, 
          x = "hp", y = "carb", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "spearman", 
          xlab = "x1", ylab = "x2")
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I know its a singular problem of my system. I hope someone can come to a possible solution starting from the error message.

Comment: It is very likely to be a problem with you having set your output decimal to a comma with options(OutDec = ",").
See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely answer to your problem is that **you have set your output decimal to a comma with `options(OutDec = ",")`**
I had the exact same problem. Here is my question with the following answer: [Error in parse(text ...) unexpected comma "," when plotting ggplot with ggpubr::stat_cor and output decimal set to comma (options(OutDec = ","))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74433033/14839884)

> This is a bug in the package ggpubr as it cannot handle commas as
> decimal seperators. For more information see here or in the comments:
>
> MrFlick: Specifically I think it's in this line
> https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/blob/ac5a01f586a5f0b47260fed071e79be36ef3f8ea/R/stat_cor.R#L207
> . Those values should be wrapped in quotes to prevent the parsing
> error. And the problem with the persistent decimal point in the
> p-values comes from
> https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/blob/ac5a01f586a5f0b47260fed071e79be36ef3f8ea/R/stat_cor.R#L219
> . It doesn't look like the package really support a comma separator. –
>
> **However, there is a workaround (pointed out by @MrFlick) by passing the argument `, output.type="text"` in the stat_cor function e.g.:**
>
> stat_cor(show.legend = F ,label.y = c(18), method = "pearson",
> output.type="text") However, there is an edge case where this does not
> work, if p < 2.2e-16 (as with the example data) as the value of p is
> passed as a string and not a number. Otherwise it works though.