# In ggscatter in R, can I use "," instead the "." on the r and p-value?

Tags: r, decimal-point

I am using `ggscatter` for a correlation graphic. It works, with de Pearson correlation (r) correct. However, I am Brazilian, and the decimal point is defined by the "," instead of the ".".

Examples:
r = 0,81 instead the English-form r = 0.81

Can I edit this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asked a few days ago with this question: [Error in parse(text ...) unexpected comma "," when plotting ggplot with ggpubr::stat_cor and output decimal set to comma (options(OutDec = ","))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433033/error-in-parsetext-unexpected-comma-when-plotting-ggplot-with-ggpubr) You can use a workaround that is by setting the output decimal option to a comma and output type of the coefficients to text in `output.type` like this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
options(OutDec= ",") 
ggscatter(mtcars, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          add = "reg.line", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, 
          cor.coeff.args = list(method = "pearson", output.type="text"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/512) on GitHub for this.